# Polymer CSS Issue

Tags: javascript, css, html, polymer

So I have created a layout for polymer that could be used as a general site layout.  Which in the processes I created 2 custom elements, which are available via git hub.

The problem I am having is the CSS cannot be set for sub components.
I am thinking that is a browser issue but I am trying to verify.  It works perfectly in Chrome (of course).

But in Firefox and IE the main header does not change.
Then there are other various differences.  For example in IE if you open the search none of the drop down options appear until you click on it.  In FireFox when you open the search the layout is off.

To view it you can goto

This is the default/original layout just something for a starting point.
http://trutekinnovations.com/

This is a dark theme I am working on and how you can see the issue
http://trutekinnovations.com/jbtheme.html

This is actually for a couple of personal projects I am hoping to launch within 6 months to a year.  I know polymer is not production ready but I am betting the farm per say that it will be by that time.

Does anyone have any suggestions.  I tried turning the CSS into variables in the component but that did not work.
I was about to try pulling out the CSS and then seeing if I Could make it external and have the CSS url be a variable that defaulted to a local version.

That is what I will probably try tomorrow. The problem is I understand this is new and instead of doing what I have done in the past on new emerging technology (which is beat my head against the wall till I get it to work) I want to actually try using the community.

Plus I hope people check out my components and help me improve them.  Thanks for any tips/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve my own issue using the method I suggested about dynamically loading CSS.

I found the following site:
http://japhr.blogspot.com/2014/06/dynamically-adding-external-styles-to.html

Which I was then able to use that code to modify it so I can load a base CSS class and then load a custom theme, or multiple custom CSS.  Technically I can pull out colors and have it dynamically load the base css, and then load a default theme.  Which is probably what I will add next.

To see the code you can view the github
https://github.com/tikicoder/trutek-header-panel-drawer

To view the demos:
http://trutekinnovations.com/
http://trutekinnovations.com/jbtheme.html

It would have been nice if I could have done it using something like

I did try that but it did not pull the variable.  I could do that in the style tag and pass custom CSS, but it only worked in Chrome.